# I cant figure out why my stylesheet wont connect to my HTML program

Tags: html, css

Im getting into my coding class and for for some reason my stylesheet wont connect to my HTML program. They are both in the same folder. Im using NotePad ++

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Khira Kathleen Mcgregor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <h1>Testing Header</h1>
            <h2> Testing sub header</h2>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <footer> 
       Bazzom bazang... we do the bestest! 
       <br/>Designed by &copy;Icabad Enterprises
       <br/>
       <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" style = "text-decoration: none">
          <img src="images/validation_button_html-blue.png" alt="Validate HTML" />
       </a>
       <!-- you may need to change the name of your image link to match the one you 
       uploaded -->
             <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" style = "text-decoration: none">
         <img src="images/validation_button_css-blue.png" alt="Validate CSS" />
       </a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And my stylesheet:

```
  body
{
  /* you better change this stuff */
  margin: 300px;
  font-family: papyrus;
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
  font-size:600;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is in a 4th row in your html file, you need to end quotes in href.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML and CSS file are in the same folder, then the problem lies in your `<link>`.

The first thing I see is that you missed a quotation mark.

```
href="styles/default.css/">
```

This href is also pointing to a folder called "styles" that would contain default.css. Since they are in the same folder, your `<link>` should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The mistake is in the 4th line . If you using Both in the same folder then you should write it this way :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./default.css" />`

If in case you have a different folder structure then 

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./foldername/default.css" />`
```